# How do the argument parameters work for these nested functions?

Tags: javascript, parameters, callback, nested, execution

I am working improving my understanding of higher order functions and callbacks within Javascript. My code here gives me the output I'm looking for, but I'm not exactly sure how it's all working. My confusion is how the arguments work for **callback** within **filterArray** and how that gets passed through to **eitherCallback** which actually takes two parameters: **callback1** and **callback2**, which are functions. Technically **callback** (in **filterArray**) is taking a number, so how does that get passed through to **eitherCallback** if **eitherCallback**'s two parameters are stored as functions? I'm super new to Javascript so your time and kindness is appreciated. :)

```
function eitherCallback(callback1, callback2) {
  return num => callback1(num) || callback2(num); 
}

function filterArray(array, callback) {
  const newArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    if (callback(array[i], i, array)) newArray.push(array[i]);
  }
  return newArray;
}
const arrOfNums = [10, 35, 105, 9];
const integerSquareRoot = n => Math.sqrt(n) % 1 === 0;
const over100 = n => n > 100;
const intSqRtOrOver100 = eitherCallback(integerSquareRoot, over100);
console.log(filterArray(arrOfNums, intSqRtOrOver100)); // should log: [105, 9]
```

Comment: why is `callback(array[i], i, array)` taking three arguments?

Comment: I think this challenge was just trying to illustrate how filter works, so it put in the 3 filter parameters here even though it's not necessary. It was already written like that in the challenge and the goal of the challenge was to write the `eitherCallback` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant point here is just that `eitherCallback` takes two callbacks (that is, two functions) and *returns another function*. Functions in JavaScript are "first class" values - which doesn't just mean they can be passed as arguments to other functions, they can also be returned from functions. You can see very clearly that `eitherCallback` returns a function from its single line with the `return` statement - what it returns is

```
num => callback1(num) || callback2(num)
```

which is a function expression. Specifically, it's a function that calls `callback1` and* `callback2`, and returns the "logical or" of their results.

So the `callback` given to `filterArray` does indeed take a single numeric parameter. That function here is `eitherCallback(integerSquareRoot, over100)` - a function that takes a number and tells you if it either has an integer square root or is over 100.

To summarise: `eitherCallback` takes the two callbacks it's passed and returns another callback - this resulting callback is the one passed to `filterArray`. Please let me know if I can make anything clearer.

*strictly speaking it doesn't always, due to short-circuiting of `||`. But this doesn't matter unless the functions have side effects, which the ones used here don't

Answer (score 3):

I wish to emphasise and expand on what @RobinZigmond has written:

They key point to understand is this:

(1) when you pass a function as an argument, you do not need to also pass the arguments that the function relies on with it - these arguments can be supplied later on.

Perhaps work through the following example closely in your web. Here is a simplified example of what you've done above:

```
function a(someNumber){ return someNumber;}

function b(functionArgument){ return functionArgument;}
```

So now when I do this:

```
b(a)   // => function a(someNumber) // of course if I pass in `a` as an argument to the `b` function, then i will get `a` back!!
```

I can assign this to a constant:

```
   const c = b(a);   // when i pass a function, I do not need to pass in the argument that a requires - which is also a number.

   c // => function a(someNumber)  // to be expected

   c(3) // => returns 3!
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at this function:

```
function eitherCallback(callback1, callback2) {
  return num => callback1(num) || callback2(num); 
}
```

This is returning a new function that has a single parameter for `num`.

So if we break it down further:

Here you are assigning intSqRtOrOver100 to the return value of the above function, which is indeed also a function .

```
const intSqRtOrOver100 = eitherCallback(integerSquareRoot, over100);
```

The function eitherCallback has access to the outer scope params `(callback1, callback2)` while also having access to the inner scope `num` param when calling the returned function.
This technique is what's called a **Closure**.

Also, there are built in functions in javascript in the Array object for filtering, reducing etc.
e.g.
You can pass it an already declared function directly e.g.

```
const filteredArray = arrOfNums.filter( intSqRtOrOver100 );
```

or you can do it inline:

e.g

```
const filteredArray = arrOfNums.filter( num => ( integerSquareRoot(num) || over100(num) ) )
```

Or

```
const filteredArray = arrOfNums.filter( num => (
  Math.sqrt(num) % 1 === 0 ||
  num > 100
) );
```

Comment: You reminded me of how I need to review closures and also go over filter so I can learn more methods in Javascript! Thanks for your time :)